# Finding if a given number is in a given range based on a flag

Tags: python, beginner, programming-challenge

Question Description:

> Given a number `n`, return `True` if `n` is in the range 1..10, inclusive. Unless `outsideMode` is True, in which case return `True` if the number is less or equal to 1, or greater or equal to 10.
>
> ```
> in1to10(5, False) → **True**
>
> in1to10(11, False) → **False**
>
> in1to10(11, True) → **True**
> ```

The link to the problem is [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p158497).

Below is my first attempt.  Please feel free to review it based on best practices, style and any other efficient solution.

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
    if(n>1 and n<10):
        return not outside_mode
    else:
        return outside_mode or n is 10 or n is 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please feel free to review it based on best practices, style and any other efficient solution.

[@mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka) already provided a more natural alternative implementation I completely agree with: following the logic precisely as in the problem statement is natural and easy to understand. I think the reason why it's easier to understand than yours has to do with the fact that the ranges being evaluated in the 2 distinct cases depending on the value of `outside_mode` have an overlap on the values 1 and 10. If the two ranges were complements of each other, things would be simpler.

As for style:

> ```
> if(n>1 and n<10):
>     return not outside_mode
> else:
>     return outside_mode or n is 10 or n is 1
> ```

The parentheses in the `if` condition are redundant.
And [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends to put spaces around operators, so this would be better:

```
if n > 1 and n < 10:
```

Even better is to use Python's kick-ass `... < ... < ...` operator:

```
if 1 < n < 10:
```

Be careful with using `is`. In this example it works as expected, but if you try to use for non-primitive types, it might not give what you expect:

```
>>> [1, 2] is [1, 2]
False
>>> (1, 2) is (1, 2)
False
```

Unless there is a specific reason to use `is`, I think you should use `==`:

```
return outside_mode or n == 10 or n == 1
```

Comment: It's not just non-primitive types: [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/222914)

Answer (score 7):

The logic is confusing. A direct translation of the problem specification is possible, and clearer.

Let's deal with the first half of the problem:

> Given a number \$n\$, return `True` if \$n\$ is in the range \$1 ..10\$, inclusive.

Then it's natural to write:

```
def in1to10(n):
    return 1 <= n <= 10
```

Now we can deal with the second half:

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
    if outside_mode:
        return n <= 1 or n >= 10
    return 1 <= n <= 10
```

Comment: Well you could do this but I tried to use python's verbose mode for high level translation, too many logical operators make it more confusing, don't you think?

Comment: The logical operators in the original code: `and`, `not`, `or`, `or` = 4. In this answer: `or` = 1. So, not sure what you mean...

Comment: I meant <=, >= mainly, where is =4 btw? :-s

Comment: janos means that there are 4 logical operators in the original code. In mjolka's answer there are only 1 (`or`).

Comment: sorry I meant relational operators, my bad!!

Comment: the right branch of his version should be reduced to `not outside_mode`

Comment: @Anirudh following the logic precisely in the question like mjolka did is very easy to understand. Your solution is somehow less easy to understand. Perhaps because of the special treatment of `1` and `10`. It seems more logical to handle the `outside_mode` condition first, because its value separates two different kind of ranges that are not completements of each other, but overlap on 1 and 10

Answer (score 2):

Questions like this generally involve working out how to understand boolean operations. There is a difference between that understanding, and making things readable, but, your solution is:

> ```
> def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
>     if(n>1 and n<10):
>         return not outside_mode
>     else:
>         return outside_mode or n is 10 or n is 1
> ```

I don't find that to be particularly horrible to read, but I think it is missing the point of whatever lesson you are supposed to be learning.

I actually prefer the [suggestion from @mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66969/31503)):

> ```
> def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
>     if outside_mode:
>         return n <= 1 or n >= 10
>     return 1 <= n <= 10
> ```

because it makes the 'flag' the logical differentiator. If it was me, I would write it @mjolka's way

On the other hand, the exercise is probably trying to teach you that you can `!=` two boolean values as an XOR operation (or alternatively use `==` as a NOT-XOR operation). Consider the following two boolean variables: `old` and `working`:

`old != working` is true when you're `old` and not `working`, or `working` and not `old`. It is false when you're `old` and `working`, or you're not `old` and not `working`. Since young people are supposed to be working, and old people are supposed to be retired, and assuming that people are happy in these states, then you could say:

```
happy = old != working
```

How does this relate to your problem?

Well, consider the following function:

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
    return n is 10 or n is 1 or (outside_mode != (1 < n < 10))
```

But, the line:

```
return n is 10 or n is 1 or (outside_mode != (1 < n < 10))
```

is probably the better way to do it all as a single boolean expression rather than the (more readable?) if-statement.

When I run that in this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
    return n is 10 or n is 1 or (outside_mode != (1 < n < 10))

for i in range(-5, 15):
    print('input {:3d} inside {:5s}   outside {:5s}'
       .format(i, str(in1to10(i, False)), str(in1to10(i, True))))
```

I get the output:

> ```
> input  -5 inside False   outside True 
> input  -4 inside False   outside True 
> input  -3 inside False   outside True 
> input  -2 inside False   outside True 
> input  -1 inside False   outside True 
> input   0 inside False   outside True 
> input   1 inside True    outside True 
> input   2 inside True    outside False
> input   3 inside True    outside False
> input   4 inside True    outside False
> input   5 inside True    outside False
> input   6 inside True    outside False
> input   7 inside True    outside False
> input   8 inside True    outside False
> input   9 inside True    outside False
> input  10 inside True    outside True 
> input  11 inside False   outside True 
> input  12 inside False   outside True 
> input  13 inside False   outside True 
> input  14 inside False   outside True
> ```

---

**Note:** What I am trying to say is that even though the boolean logic XOR is what the exercise probably wants, I would still write it with an if-statement (like @mjolka), but you still need to understand how the boolean XOR would work.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Python supports double-ended inequalities.  To implement just the first part, write

```
def in1to10(n):
    return 1 <= n <= 10
```

Adding support for `outsideMode`…

```
def in1to10(n, outsideMode):
    if outsideMode:
        return not(1 < n < 10)
    else:
        return 1 <= n <= 10
```

Unfortunately, `outsideMode` isn't `not(1 <= n <= 10)`, so you can't do anything clever with XOR, like

```
# Wrong!
def in1to10(n, outsideMode):
    return outsideMode ^ (1 <= n <= 10)
```

(Well, you *could*, but the added complication is not worth it.)

### Style notes

In Python, it is conventional to omit parentheses for simple `if` conditions.  It is also more common to use `lower_case_with_underscores` for parameter and local/instance variable names.  See examples in [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

CodingBat is inconsistent in the naming: it uses `outsideMode` in the question, and `outside_mode` in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your original code does not work correctly, as taking your code:

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
    if(n>1 and n<10):
        return not outside_mode
    else:
        return outside_mode or n is 10 or n is 1
```

and calling it in this manner, with the expected output in the comment next to the func call:

```
print in1to10(-1, False)            # → **False**
print in1to10(-1, True)             # → **True**
print in1to10(1, False)             # → **True**
print in1to10(1, True)              # → **False**
print in1to10(10, False)            # → **True**
print in1to10(10, True)             # → **False**
print in1to10(5, False)             # → **True**
print in1to10(5, True)              # → **False**
print in1to10(11, False)            # → **False**
print in1to10(11, True)             # → **True**
print in1to10("adsf", "Asdf")       # False
```

produces these responses (output  → **expected_output**):

```
False  → **False**
True   → **True**
True   → **True**
True   → **False**
True   → **True**
True   → **False**
True   → **True**
False  → **False**
False  → **False**
True   → **True**
Asdf   → **False**
```

Notice that your original answer does not catch nor raise an error when encountering a string val.

I've reworked your code to this:

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode=False):
    retval = True if outside_mode == False else False
    return retval if 1 <= n <= 10 else not retval
```

which does the following:

1. It defaults outside_mode to False, so that we can omit it and only give it a number to check if its within the range
2. Checks if n is within a range elegantly
3. Uses the retval var as a flip switch boolean
4. Handles strings and outputs False if its a string
5. Correctly outputs the expected output

This is the output of my version of the func (using the same calls and expected output as above in the original call)  (output  → **expected_output**):

```
False  → **False**
True   → **True**
True   → **True**
False  → **False**
True   → **True**
False  → **False**
True   → **True**
False  → **False**
False  → **False**
True   → **True**
False  → **False**
```

Comment: The specification makes it quite clear that the numbers 1 and 10 are in range in both modes.

Comment: Good point...in my defense, this was written up at 2am :)

Comment: hey take some rest..